# DisposedObjectException in VB

Tags: vb.net, dockpanel-suite

I am using the [DockPanel Suite](http://dockpanelsuite.sourceforge.net) from SourceForge and whenever I open a document and close it, but open it again, I get a an error saying "Cannot access a disposed object". What can I do to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, I found the correct answer at http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/forums/forum/402316/topic/1985140